# Eccentricity and Keplerian orbit

Tags: dynamical-systems

A particle is moving in elliptical orbit, with ecccentricity $e$. Let $r(t)$ be the distance of the particle from one focus. Seeing this as a perturbed circular motion, one find that $r(t)=\frac{1}{2}(1-e\cos(t))+O(e^2)$. Now every book or article says that this is a known fact, and moreover some authors say $e$ is the eccentricity while some others say it's eccentric anomaly (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly).
How can one arrives to this expression? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the units of $r(t)$? And what is $t$? (I would assume it is not the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "exact" normalized expression for the polar equation of conic section curve with the Sun placed at the origin is 
$$r(t)=\frac{r_0}{1+e \cos(t)}.$$

(here, you have taken $r_0=\frac12$). See for that first Kepler's law in

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion

Thus, consider expansion $$\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}\approx 1-\epsilon+\epsilon^2-...$$ and stop at order $2$.

Comment: So I arrive to the formulae setting $\epsilon = e\cos(t)$ and applying that Taylor expasion?

Comment: That's right. Of course, the assumption is that $e<<1$ which is the case for (almost) all planets.

Comment: Thank you very much!